# Both internal and external vertex labels in the package tkz-graph?

Tags: tkz-graph

I'm drawing graphs in which I want to label vertices (e.g. x, y, z, w, etc), but also attach the value of a function calculated at each vertex (e.g. 4, -3, 2, 7 corresponding to vertices x, y, z, w etc).  I'd like to achieve this by having x inside the vertex and the value of the function on the outside, though if there are other ways of achieving this easily I'd be open to that.

Is it possible to use the `tkz-graph` package to achieve this? I have read the documentation and (notwithstanding that my French is very rusty), I haven't been able to figure this out. Also open to alternative (simple & easy) packages that would allow me to achieve this.

(My level of LaTeX is $< \epsilon$)

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal]
    \SetGraphUnit{2}
    \SetVertexMath
    \Vertex{x}
    \Vertex[LabelOut, L=$4$, Lpos=90]{x} % this just replaces the internal label doesn't add an outside label
    \EA(x){y}
    \NOEA(y){z}
    \SOEA(z){w}
    \Edges(x,y,z,w,y,z) 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Welcome. // Unfortunately, compiling your code fragment results in Errors starting with "! LaTeX Error: Environment tikzpicture undefined.". Please make your code ready to compile. Thank you

Comment: Thanks.  I think you need to load the package, so I added that \usepackage line

Comment: Thank you. You are on a good track: did you try to compile it? It still can‘t …

Comment: "(My level of LaTeX is $< \epsilon$)" // For Latex I suggest getting one of the books, or use this online book: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX, or Overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Learn_LaTeX_in_30_minutes . // For Tikz I suggest e.g. the tutorials in the pgf-manual https://tikz.dev/ , Overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package#Introduction etc. // With this background you can at least walk through the examples in the tkz-manual, which basically follows the Tikz-path.

Comment: I've been trying to avoid delving too deep into `tikz`, and instead relying on the packages built on top, like `tkz-graph` and `tikz-cd`, as my focus is studying maths rather than LaTeX, but it looks like I'm going to have to study `tikz`.

Comment: Ok. Well, I tried to suggest to get some notion about Tikz, and also LatexThe rest will come over time from using it one way or the other. It‘s like walking or riding a bike: once you can do it, in hindsight it appears being „easy“ …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it: mixing `tkz-graph` (built on Tikz) with plain `Tikz`.

#### Some hints

`Tikz` needs a semicolon `;` at each end of a line to know "this path shall finish here". Think of a `path` being a series of commands to be executed, which we perceive as "drawing something".  `tkz-graph` already provides this `;` internally, so you can write them without this indicator. (And you can also mix both approaches.)

So in the first part just draw your structure with `tkz-graph`:

```
    \Vertex{x}      % default position: at (0,0)
    \EA     (x){y}  % EAst of x
    \NOEA   (y){z}  % NOrthEAst of y
    \SOEA   (z){w}  % SOuthEAst of z
    
    \Edges(x,y,z,w,y,z)
```

To place your labels just use ordinary `\node`s from `Tikz`, like so:

- place a `\node`
- at the coordinate from `(x)`, previously defined
- and put as text `{ }`
- some Latex-compliant text, here in math mode `$4$`
- and finish this path, i.e. this single command, by `;`

```
    % ~~~ and now some ordinary Tikz to place text in math mode $ $ ~~~
    %     kindly watch the semicolon ; needed here
    \node[abv]  at (x) {$4$};
    \node[bel]  at (y) {$-3$};
...
```

The styles `abv` and `bel` are defined in the beginning, and just shift the label a bit up and down, i.e. into y-direction. (Perhaps it's also available as a shortcut in tkz-graph.)

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[   % defining some own styles
    abv/.style={yshift=6mm},
    bel/.style={yshift=-6mm},
 ]
...
```

#### Final results

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[   % defining some own styles
    abv/.style={yshift=6mm},
    bel/.style={yshift=-6mm},
 ]
    \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal]
    \SetGraphUnit{2}
    \SetVertexMath
    
    \Vertex{x}      % default position: at (0,0)
    \EA     (x){y}  % EAst of x
    \NOEA   (y){z}  % NOrthEAst of y
    \SOEA   (z){w}  % SOuthEAst of z
    
    \Edges(x,y,z,w,y,z) 
    
    % ~~~ and now some ordinary Tikz to place text in math mode $ $ ~~~
    %     kindly watch the semicolon ; needed here
    \node[abv]  at (x) {$4$};
    \node[bel]  at (y) {$-3$};
    \node[abv]  at (z) {$2$};
    \node[bel]  at (w) {$7$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  It sounds like there's no obvious trick within `tkz-graph` to add multiple vertex labels that I'm not using. Thank you also for the explanation of each of the steps - e.g. the importance of `;` . I'll try this out.

Comment: Right, tkz-graph allows some style changes on the vertices, but no double-label so to say, as far as I see it.